# CSS filter grayscale image for IE 10

Tags: css, filter, internet-explorer-10, grayscale

Is there a way to make grayscale image filter work on IE 10 without JavaScript or SVG?

I've been using the following code successfully in all browsers except IE 10.

```
img{
filter:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter     id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /*     Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
filter:gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter:grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
-o-filter: grayscale(100%);}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This approach only works in WebKit and Firefox. It doesn’t work in IE or Opera. WebKit is currently the only browser to support CSS filters, while Firefox supports SVG filters on HTML. Opera and IE support SVG filters, but only for SVG content.

There is no good way to make this work in IE10, as it dropped support for the legacy IE filters. There is a way, however, I’d not recommend it.

You can set IE10 to render using IE9 standards mode using the following meta element in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

This will turn support back on for legacy IE filters. However, it has the side effect of dropping IE into IE9 mode, where the latest advancements in IE10 will no longer be supported. In your case it may be possible that you do not need these new features currently, but if you go down this road, you’d need to be aware of it when updating the site in future.

Comment: This will not work: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/06/04/legacy-dx-filters-removed-from-ie10-release-preview.aspx

Comment: Firefox 35 was just released and now supports CSS Filters https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/35

Answer (score 3):

http://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/cross-browser-grayscale-image-example-using-css3-js/

http://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/cross-browser-grayscale-image-example-using-css3-js-v2-0-with-browser-feature-detection-using-modernizr/

The above links give good idea for > IE10 and other browsers.

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cross browser solution using HTML5 and jquery using fade effect

[Code](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/html5-grayscale-image-hover/comment-page-8)

[Demo](http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/html5-grayscale/)

Code:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // On window load. This waits until images have loaded which is essential
    $(window).load(function(){

        // Fade in images so there isn't a color "pop" document load and then on window load
        $(".item img").fadeIn(500);

        // clone image
        $('.item img').each(function(){
            var el = $(this);
            el.css({"position":"absolute"}).wrap("<div class='img_wrapper' style='display: inline-block'>").clone().addClass('img_grayscale').css({"position":"absolute","z-index":"998","opacity":"0"}).insertBefore(el).queue(function(){
                var el = $(this);
                el.parent().css({"width":this.width,"height":this.height});
                el.dequeue();
            });
            this.src = grayscale(this.src);
        });

        // Fade image 
        $('.item img').mouseover(function(){
            $(this).parent().find('img:first').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
        })
        $('.img_grayscale').mouseout(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
        });     
    });

    // Grayscale w canvas method
    function grayscale(src){
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imgObj = new Image();
        imgObj.src = src;
        canvas.width = imgObj.width;
        canvas.height = imgObj.height; 
        ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0); 
        var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for(var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
            for(var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
                var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
                var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
                imgPixels.data[i] = avg; 
                imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg; 
                imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
            }
        }
        ctx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
        return canvas.toDataURL();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Code added. Good luck.