# filter invert not working in IE (Internet Explorer)

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

filter invert not working in IE (Internet Explorer)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
</script>

<style>
    .normalColor {
        filter: invert(0%);
    }
    .invertedColor {
        filter: invert(100%);
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<U><b>Normal image</b></U><br>
<img id="home" src="image.png" alt="Smiley face" width="500" height="300" class="normalColor">
<br>
<U><b>Invert image</b></U><br>
<img id="home" src="image.png" alt="Smiley face" width="500" height="300" class="invertedColor">
</body>

</html>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v2xb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

CSS filters are only works in WebKit and Firefox. It doesn’t work in IE or Opera. WebKit is currently the only browser to support CSS filters.

There is no good way to make this work in IE, as it dropped support for the legacy IE filters.

Comment: any another way, to do

Comment: give me suggestion

Comment: nothing bro i was make research for this thing before 3-4 days ago related to filter support in IE but its doesn't works. I tried to implement this for my own website but i can't.

Comment: you can try this thing if it works. I tried to make this solution but its not work for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407268/css-filter-grayscale-image-for-ie-10

Comment: I will try your link

Comment: told you bro its not working its just west of time.

Comment: Is there any alternative?

Comment: and one more this open this link in IE and read the note on top. 
https://www.cssfiltergenerator.com/

Comment: this link clearly say that filter had no support in IE.

Comment: i need some help about invert color

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate from this [Invert filter not working on IE and safari](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35997521/11393315). You can try what the accepted answer suggested.

Also try to practice using this tool, https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters .